# Is there any Eclipse virgo simple project?

Tags: sample, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to check out osgi on web applications. I googled and found out the best way to go would be using spring osgi and virgo. I can't find an easy to setup sample project. Can anyone help me?

update- I should have mentioned that I have a little experience in OSGi(Equinox). And I checked some OSGi frameworks such as Apache Felix, Eclipse Equinox(with the tomcat bundle),... But I want to have my first experiment with Virgo.

Comment: OK, but I thought you have done the things you said! So I was wondering how to switch from felix to the Virgo. (you said that's easy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [Virgo Snaps](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.0.2.RELEASE/docs/snaps-guide/html/index.html) project, using the 3.0.2.RELEASE of Virgo.
It takes a little bit extra time to configure Snaps (adding it to Virgo, and editing the org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.properties file, as mentioned in the docs). But then you have a simple yet modular web application running with a single spring controller.

There's also the [Greenpages example](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/samples/) that shows how to build a fully working, yet more complex webapp connected to a database. But I think taking a look at the snaps example (not concentrating too much on the Snaps internals) is a good way to start.

Good luck! :)

Comment: tnx. Just another question! Is there an eclipse plugin or something like that for virgo bundle developement?

Comment: I'd recommend using Springsource Tool Suite + Virgo server adapter (is part of the virgo tooling): http://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/Tooling. Oh and btw, in the meantime virgo 3.5 M2 is also working with the Virgo Tooling, so you might want to try that version.